# Migrate data from cassandra to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We have 2 cassandra clusters, first one has the old data and second one has the new data.

Now we want to move or copy the old data from first cluster to second. What is the best way to do this and how to do this?

we are using DSE 3.1.4.

Comment: Do these clusters have the same keyspace configured? What is the replication? Do you want all of the data replicated between the two clusters or only to reside on the second cluster?

Comment: The name of the keysapce has to be changed and the 1st cluster has one primary key and second cluster which we need to copy data has composite primary key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tool you could try would be the COPY TO/FROM cqlsh command.

On a node in the old cluster, you would use the COPY TO:

```
cqlsh> COPY myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) TO 'temp.csv'
```

And then (after copying the file over) on a node in your new cluster, you would copy the data in the CSV file into Cassandra:

```
cqlsh> COPY myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) FROM 'temp.csv'
```

Here is some more documentation on the [COPY](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command.

Note that the COPY TO/FROM is recommended for tables that contain only a few million rows or less.  For larger datasets you should look at:

- [Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html)
- [sstable2json](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/tools/toolsSStable2json_t.html)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention earlier, I have different schema ( Added a composite primary key ) in the new cluster. Is this will still work?

Comment: I had 350GB of data which will be faster?

Comment: If the schema is different, you can specify how you want to map each column; so that's ok.  Is the 350GB all one table?  If so, could try using COPY, but I think the Bulk Loader might be your best bet.

Comment: 350GB on whole cluster. It's not in one table

Comment: If it's 350 for the whole cluster, then definitely give COPY a try.

Comment: Well, it looks like COPY is your only option, as that should allow you to modify the column/key names.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called /usr/bin/sstableloader for copying data between the clusters. Although when I used it months ago, I encountered an error and used [this](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/sstableloader-unrecognized-option-tf#post-13436) instead. But since it was a long time ago, sstableloader might have been fixed already.